# codeigniter - send email wamp gmail

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, email, wampserver

I read other topics but not resolved my problem..

I have this in my controller:

```
$this->load->library("email");  
$this->email->from(set_value("email"),
set_value("nome"),set_value("msg"));  
$this->email->to("my@gmail.com");
$this->email->subject("Mensagem");
$this->email->message(set_value("msg"));
$this->email->send();
echo  $this->email->print_debugger();
```

and my library email:

```
var $useragent = "CodeIgniter";
var $mailpath       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";
var $protocol       = "smtp";
var $smtp_host      = "smtp.gmail.com";
var $smtp_user      = "xxx@gmail.com";
var $smtp_pass      = "xxx";
var $smtp_port      = "465";
var $smtp_timeout   = 5;
var $smtp_crypto    = "";
var $wordwrap       = TRUE;
var $wrapchars      = "76";
var $mailtype       = "html";
var $charset        = "utf-8";
var $multipart      = "mixed";
var $alt_message    = '';   
var $validate       = FALSE;
var $useragent = "CodeIgniter";
var $mailpath       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail";
var $protocol       = "smtp";
var $smtp_host      = "smtp.gmail.com";
var $smtp_user      = "xxx@gmail.com";
var $smtp_pass      = "xxx";
var $smtp_port      = "465";
var $smtp_timeout   = 5;
var $smtp_crypto    = "";
var $wordwrap       = TRUE;
var $wrapchars      = "76";
var $mailtype       = "html";
var $charset        = "utf-8";
var $multipart      = "mixed";
var $alt_message    = '';   
var $validate       = FALSE;
```

...

I also change php.ini for: (wamp - bin - apache - apache2.4.4 - bin - php.ini)

> extension=php_openssl.dll

But I have da same problem... not work:

> Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1553
>   Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Line Number 1553 for email.php have this:

> if ( ! mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this->_header_str, "-f ".$this->clean_email($this->_headers['From']))){
>   return FALSE;}else{
>   return TRUE;}

```
if ( ! mail($this->_recipients, $this->_subject, $this->_finalbody, $this-_header_str, "-f ".$this->clean_email($this->_headers['From']))){
    return FALSE;
}else{
    return TRUE;
}
```

I need help... tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this self TESTED Code. It may help you.
Make sure you have POP3 enabled in gmail Settings.

```
$config['useragent']    = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user']    = '*****developer@gmail.com'; // Your gmail id
$config['smtp_pass']    = '**********'; // Your gmail Password
$config['smtp_port']    = 465;
$config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;    
$config['wrapchars']    = 76;
$config['mailtype']     = 'html';
$config['charset']      = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['validate']     = FALSE;
$config['priority']     = 3;
$config['newline']      = "\r\n";
$config['crlf']         = "\r\n";

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('trimantradeveloper@gmail.com', 'TSS DEV');
$this->email->to('trimantra@trimantra.com'); 
$this->email->cc('trimantra@gmail.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');    

$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_user'] = "blablabla@gmail.com"; 
$config['smtp_pass'] = "yourpassword";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$ci->email->initialize($config);

$ci->email->from('blablabla@gmail.com', 'Blabla');
$list = array('xxx@gmail.com');
$ci->email->to($list);
$this->email->reply_to('my-email@gmail.com', 'Explendid Videos');
$ci->email->subject('This is an email test');
$ci->email->message('It is working. Great!');
$ci->email->send();
```

put **WAMP** server to **online** also...