# godaddy codeigniter email sending but not arriving

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Sorry, yet another `godaddy/codeigniter` email problem. Apologies if there is a similar answered post on here but I could not find one that worked for me.

I have moved my (working) site from local to `GoDaddy` and after trying various settings I have the following in the email config

```
$config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
$config['mailpath']            = "/usr/sbin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
$config['protocol']            = "sendmail";
$config['smtp_host']           = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$config['smtp_port']           = "25";
$config['smtp_user']    = 'myemail@mygodaddydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'mypassword';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

Unlike the vast majority of similar posts on here my emails appear to be sending because if I use

```
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I get the following:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: sendmail
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 12 Feb 2014 14:02:34 -0700
From: "me" <>
Return-Path: <>
To: email@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Please_reset_your_password_at_CellKulture?=
Reply-To: "" <>
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <52fbe16a8c43a>
Mime-Version: 1.0
```

BUT the email never arrives at my address. I have tried sending emails to a gmail and another address. Can you help?

Comment: Shared hosting? Then you must wait for 20-30 minutes

Comment: 20-30 minutes from the time I sent the email? REALLY. if that is true its time to migrate to amazon

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235711/godaddy-emailing-really-slow)

Comment: Thanks, wow I assumed I had got this wrong. Never thought it could be that bad. Sendgrid seems like the solution though, thanks

Comment: I left this overnight and still no emails appearing so it looks like tgere might be an issue. Can anyone find a problem with my code or should i contact godaddy?

Comment: I think your code is fine because you got the successfull message. Goahead and contact godaddy.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. I'm having little difference in config options which you can see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961455/codeigniter-send-email-wamp-gmail/20965286#20965286. this settings works for me on Godaddy Server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961455/codeigniter-send-email-wamp-gmail/20965286#20965286

Comment: Working solution using smtp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961455/codeigniter-send-email-wamp-gmail/20965286#20965286

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After two long days, I solved this using the following configuration:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_user'] = '';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '';
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;

$this->load->library('email', $config);
```

I'm using CodeIgniter in Godaddy server.

The message is delivered in 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Guys use this, don't band your head for smtp!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in the end by using sendgrid and bypassing godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Does't recive email on go daddy webmail than go to cpanel search email routing and select Remote Mail Exchanger option than click on change button.
after that changes this code works for me.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'your_email';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'your_password';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->config->load('email', TRUE);
$mail_config = $this->config->item('email');

$data = array(
         'username'=> 'your_email',
         'content' => 'Send mail',
             );
             
$this->load->library('email'); 
$this->email->initialize($mail_config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('your_email');
$this->email->to('your_email');
$this->email->subject('subject');

$this->email->message($this->load->view('email/' . $type . '-html', $datas, TRUE));
$this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/' . $type . '-txt', $datas, TRUE));

if ($this->email->send(FALSE))
    return TRUE;
else
    return FALSE;
```